# script src becomes a url in jade with nodejs + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a web application with nodejs + jade.

I want to include a js file into my jade page. But it doesn't work as I thought it should do.

I include three js files:

```
script(src='//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js')
script(src='//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src="async.js")
```

The first two work well (bootstrap files). But the browser will claim at the third one "GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/sample/auth/async.js 404 (Not Found)". It seems that some thing changes the src to a url with the base url "http://127.0.0.1:3000/sample/auth/"

"127.0.0.1" is localhost and port "3000" is the port the server is listening to, and "http://127.0.0.1:3000/sample" is the entrance of my web application.

So I guess there is a configuration in the project to force the src be a url like that. And I don't know how to include local js files. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: The last script tag is going to include a script relative to the URL of the page it's referenced. Where is the `async.js` script located?

Comment: I put async.js to the same directory as the web page file(shuffler.jade) locates (views/pages/async.js). And how could I include a local file? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `async.js` in `/public/scripts` in your Express app. You'll probably need to create this directory, but you'll see that your app's local CSS files are located there in `/public/stylesheets`.

Once you do this, reference your `async.js` file like this `script(src='/scripts/async.js')`.

This is the preferred method for serving local CSS and JavaScript. You can see in `app.js` see that Express looks there for any static resources.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`